# Is there away to fix the JTable same is before search?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

i have a jtable as shown in the pictures  with 2 JDateChooser when i search and populate the table it loses the cell render is there a way to fix it ?
i have tried alot of things suggested but none worked

this is the action for the button for searching and seting the mode

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                try {

                    java.sql.Date lowerdate = new java.sql.Date(dateChooser.getDate().getTime());
                    java.sql.Date upperdate =  new java.sql.Date(dateChooser_1.getDate().getTime());
                    Connection con = DerbyConnection.dbConnector();

                    PreparedStatement   pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from COMPANYCHEKS  WHERE CHEKSDATEIN >= ? AND CHEKSDATEIN <= ?");
                    pstmt.setDate(1, lowerdate);
                    pstmt.setDate(2,upperdate);
                    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(Menu32.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

here is my model set to be called for populating the table with the result

```
 public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
                try {
                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
                    int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

                    columnNames.add("الرمز");
                    columnNames.add("العميل");
                    columnNames.add("البنك");
                    columnNames.add("تاريخ الشك");
                    columnNames.add("رقم الشك");
                    columnNames.add("القيمة");
                    columnNames.add("العملة");
                    columnNames.add("سعر الصرف");
                    columnNames.add("القيمة بالدولار");
                    columnNames.add("تاريخ الإيداع");
                    columnNames.add("بنك الإيداع");
                    columnNames.add("الحالة");
                    columnNames.add("ملاحظات");



                    // Get all rows.
                    Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                    Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                        newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                    }

                    rows.addElement(newRow);
                    }

                    return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }


            }
```

here you can see what happens

Table before search:

[image]

table after populate:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i search and populate the table it loses the cell render is there a way to fix it ?

By default, when you create set a new model to the table, a new TableColumnModel is created based on the new data in the TableModel and you lose the custom renderers.

Assuming the columns of the model are the same and only the rows of data changed you can prevent the TableColumnModel from be creating by invoking:

```
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
```

after you have created the JTable with the original TableModel.

Comment: didnt try it yet my insert code to the database having some errors cuz iam have a double and it says "Invalid character string format for type DOUBLE."

Comment: Thanks again for your help